# Express converting nested arrays into string

Tags: express, axios, body-parser

I'm trying to pass nested arrays parameters from React App to Express Server via axios. Client side and URL format looks good but on server side these nested arrays' items are converted into string

**POST nested array output:**

```
filter = [[1], [2], [3]]
```

**Express server received *req.query* output**

```
filter = ['[1]', '[2]', '[3]']
```

so it fails because it's expecting nested arrays.

**Request URL**

http://localhost:3006/api/filtertable?page=0&pageSize=5&isFilter=true&filter[]=[1]&filter[]=[2]&filter[]=[3]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that GET requests with parameters can only accept primitive data and arrays of primitive data.

Now you could parse these values on your server like so:

```
app.get('/api/filterable', (req, res, next) => {
 var filter = req.query.filter.map(f => JSON.parse(f));
 // Do whatever else you need with it
});
```

Or you could also use a different HTTP method that allows sending JSON data, like POST.